# How does the polynomial transformation $P(x) \mapsto P(x) + c$ alter the roots of that polynomial? Specifics inside.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider a real quadratic polynomial $Q_k(x) = (x-\nu)(x-\omega_k) - g_k^2$. I can interpret $Q_k(x)$ as a translation of the polynomial
$$ (x-\nu)(x-\omega_k) = \left(x-\frac{\nu+\omega_k}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\nu-\omega_k}{2}\right)^2, $$
so the roots are mapped from $\frac{\nu+\omega_k}{2} \pm \frac{\nu-\omega_k}{2}$ to
$$\frac{\nu+\omega_k}{2} \pm \sqrt{g_k^2+\left(\frac{\nu-\omega_k}{2}\right)^2},$$
which is fantastic for my purposes because I can interpret the above expression for either small $g_k$ or small $\nu-\omega_k$.

Now consider the quartic polynomial
$$ Q_k(x)Q_\ell(x)-g_k^2g_\ell^2 = \left[(x-\nu)(x-\omega_k) - g_k^2\right] \left[(x-\nu)(x-\omega_\ell) - g_\ell^2\right] - g_k^2g_\ell^2,$$
which is nothing but a translation of the quartic $Q_k(x) Q_\ell(x)$ whose roots I already know how to compute. I would like to develop a similar formula for the new roots in terms of the old. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help to know that one of the roots of this polynomial is $\nu$.